# What are the recommended ciphers for Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

As of today, Chrome finally drops support for RC4 ciphers.

Does anyone know what the recommended list of ciphers in a `<Connector>` are for non-APR servers? I've yet to find a definitive source.

For bonus points, should any SSL protocols be disabled? (Some older articles say to disable SSLv2?)

Comment: Recommended for which scenario ? If you want to support old clients you will see different recommendations. Nonetheless: have a look at https://bettercrypto.org/static/applied-crypto-hardening.pdf. Although it does not have a specific section for Tomcat it goes into details as far as ciphers are concerned. SSLv2 and SSLv3 should be disabled, I would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has [lots](https://community.qualys.com/thread/14471) of [great](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76993/now-that-it-is-2015-what-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-should-be-used-in-a-high-securit) [results](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Modern_compatibility) if you just search for [recommended tls ciphers](https://www.google.com/search?q=recommended+tls+ciphers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Short and sweet:

1. Disable SSLv2, SSLv2Hello (not an actual protocol), and SSLv3; consider disabling TLSv1
2. Disable anything using RC4 encryption
3. Disable anything using MD5 hashing
4. Disable any cipher suite with fewer than 128 bits for symmetric encryption
5. Don't use RSA keys smaller than 3072 bits, consider using 4k
6. Put ciphers in order of preference, with higher-quality ciphers first
7. Make sure to enable "honor server cipher order" to always use the better ciphers you just configured

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this advice was good back in 2016. You should always check to see what the current best practices are for your era. Qualys's [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) is a good testing tool and has lots of information about what current best-practices are.

Answer (score 0):

APR/non APR has nothing to do with it, the list is the same for both, although the syntax is different.

Remove the RC4 ciphers, at least.

Sun/Oracle Java JSSE has never implemented SSLv2.

Comment: Note that recent versions of Tomcat allow [OpenSSL-style cipher-suite configuration for JSSE](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support). It's much nicer than explicitly-specifying every single cipher you want to use.